# Testcafe proxy is lost after calling window.location.assign() method when the website is hosted on amazon cloudfront

Tags: testing, automated-tests, amazon-cloudfront, e2e-testing, testcafe

The whole url gets replaced and I don't see the testcafe frame anymore.
It happens when the test is ran against the website being hosted on amazon cloudfront, but if I run the test against the website hosted on localhost, then the redirection works, it doesn't replace the whole url and I can still see the testcafe frame.

Redirect on localhost looks like:
`http://<testcafe-ip>:38279/I2zW8XmMh*tOCn5CTOd/<some-new-url>`

Redirect on cloudfront looks like:
`<some-new-url>`

Do you know if amazon cloudfront has some security integrated which might be preventing the website from being embedded into testcafe?

Comment: This behavior looks like a bug in the TestCafe Hammerhead proxy. I recommend you open an issue in the [TestCafe Github repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) and describe it there. A public url for debugging would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. It works after setting the flag "disablehttp2" https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#disablehttp2

It seems testcafe-hammerhead has issues with redirection and http2. For me disabling http2 is fine, but there might be cases where it's not. Hope they fix this in hammerhead.